# Authenticating processes calling a WCF service

Tags: wcf

My team is gutting a bunch of legacy code and forcibly inserting a service layer.  It's a combination of .Net, VFP, ASP, and ASP.Net.  Ugly COM objects and other bad practices.

We're moving logic from the libs and UI into a WCF service a module at a time.  We have to authenticate the user making the call, but we also want to authenticate the process that's making the request.  We don't want anyone who can access the services to be able to write scripts or apps that call our services that we don't know about.

Other than writing a custom ISAPI filter and hacking the request before send, is there a "normal" approach to locking down services to prevent anyone with a browser from making calls directly against a WCF service?

Comment: I'm looking at this exact situation as well. My current thought it to add a "VendorAPIKey" to the function calls that I create and hand out, so each call can be checked for a valid vendor record in a database. WCF also supports a scenario where both the server and client use certificates to authenticate. Don't forget though that your messages are only as safe as your transport layer!